# Using global ZodValidationPipe (nestjs-zod) to validate body that is an array of objects?

Tags: nestjs, zod

I registered ZodValidationPipe globally within my root nestjs Module per documentation:

```
{
  provide: APP_PIPE,
  useClass: ZodValidationPipe,
},
```

and that seems to be generally working - as long as what I'm validating isn't an array.

In the example below, the `@Param` validation works as expected, but the `@Body` validation is ignored since I'm expecting an array - and as DTO can't be an array itself, I need to specify the type as an array of DTOs i.e. `DocumentPostDto[]`:

```
@Post(`organizations/:orgId/documents`)
async create(
  @Param() { orgId }: DocumentsPostParamsDto,
  @Body() data: DocumentPostDto[]
): Promise<DocumentType[]> {
  return this.documentsService.create(orgId, data);
}
```

DTOs:

```
// request params

const documentsPostParamsSchema = z.object({
  orgId: z.string().uuid(),
});

export class DocumentsPostParamsDto extends createZodDto(
  documentsPostParamsSchema
) {}

// request body is an array of following DTOs

const documentPostSchema = z.object({
  name: z.string().trim().min(1),
  // ... and so on
});

export class DocumentPostDto extends createZodDto(
  documentPostSchema
) {}
```

I would very much like to make use of the fact that I have global ZodValidationPipe set up so that I don't have to do double work every time, e.g. this works but that means explicitly instantiating and defining the validation with a schema, where it could be inferred from the body's assigned dto (which is the whole point of global pipelines):

```
// dto file
export const documentArrayPostSchema = z.array(
  documentPostSchema,
);

// controller route
@Body(new ZodValidationPipe(documentArrayPostSchema)) data: DocumentPostDto[]
```

Is there any way to define the request body DTO as an array and have it validated against its assigned type as in the first example?

Comment: To clarify, my request body unfortunately has an anonymous array as the root of data, and I don't have control over that.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to do the following so Zod picks up the correct Dto signature to validate:

1. You already have:

```js
// dto file
export const documentArrayPostSchema = z.array(
  documentPostSchema,
);
```

2. So far it is not a DTO but a Zod schema, so you would have to infer a class from it:

```js
export class DocumentPostArrayDto extends createZodDto(
  documentArrayPostSchema
) {}
```

3. Lastly pass that as type in your controller's @Body request:

```js
@Post(`organizations/:orgId/documents`)
async create(
  @Param() { orgId }: DocumentsPostParamsDto,
  @Body() data: DocumentPostArrayDto
): Promise<DocumentType[]> {
  return this.documentsService.create(orgId, data);
}
```

I haven't tested this, so slight modifications may be needed, but in theory this approach should work

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work. I have initially tried that and got errors about incorrectly extending the base class. That's why I mentioned the DTO itself can't be an array so I had to use `DocumentPostDto[]` as the type.

Comment: ah, can you please edit your question and post a sample of your request?

Comment: Not much to add other than what is described above. The request is an array of objects i.e. `[{..}, {..}]`. I haven't found a way for a DTO to be an array at root level, so the DTO I have is a single object from that array, and the assigned type is then `Dto[]` which global validation pipe doesn't work with.